# WP - Get category count by date

Tags: wordpress

Is there any shortcut query to get category count by date. Like,  one need to find how many post he/she published in each category last day.

My way of doing this:

> - Fetch all post for the date from database
> - Iterate through post loop and find each post category
> - Count total number of post in each category

Is there any better way for performance reason. I have some 100 posts every day.

Comment: Absolutely, use COUNT aggregate function

Comment: @VitaliProtosovitski, You mean using  get_categories( ) ? does that accept any date parameter ? Would u plz explain a bit more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use custom SQL query

```
   global $wpdb;
    $sql = "
SELECT wp_term_taxonomy.term_id as term_id, COUNT(wp_posts.id) as count_posts
    FROM wp_posts
    INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON wp_posts.id = wp_term_relationships.object_id
    INNER JOIN wp_term_taxonomy ON wp_term_relationships.term_taxonomy_id = wp_term_taxonomy.term_id
    WHERE wp_posts.post_date >= cast(DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY) as date)
    AND wp_term_taxonomy.taxonomy = 'category'
    GROUP BY term_id
    ";
    $query = $wpdb->get_results($sql);
    foreach ($query as $u) {
        var_dump($u);
    }
```

Comment: But that query selects some non category taxonomy terms like tag and an unknown other. And also, I like to get that query extended removing user_id parameter to get all posts of that day by category regardless of users

Comment: np, updated an answer. Replace 'category' with your taxonomy name